# Bootstrap 3- fixed sidebar layout issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie in bootstrap ,
I am designing a admin panel, heres the  **[DEMO](http://bootply.com/72194)** .

I want to make the sidebar height equaly depend on right content div.
.i.e (side bar background color will be gray).

**Html Markup :**  (also want to know whether my html structure was proper)

```
   <!-- Headder row -->
    <div class="row">
       <div class="navbar"> .....  </div>
    </div>

 <!-- Content row -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- SIDEBAR Open -->
        <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-2 col-lg-2">
            ....
       </div>
   <!-- right content box -->
     <div id="content-right" class="col-lg-10 container" >
      ......
    </div
   </div>


<!-- Footer row -->
    <div class="row">
      ......   
    </div>
```

**Expected output :**
[image]

Comment: Any luck with this for bootstrap 3? currently looking at implementing something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/BM65D/

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.header{
    background-color:#00A2E8;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
.footer{
    background-color:gray;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    height:400px;
    background-color:#C3C3C3;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;  
}
.right{
    left:200px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but here you have fixed the height of left bar, and also with out using bootstrap?. i need column right,column left

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `display:table-cell` property

I have created a bootply demo => http://bootply.com/100790

Steps:

Add another class to your wrapper like .mainwrap and in CSS

```
.mainwrap {
 display:table;
}
```

Add CSS to sidebar left and content right

```
.sidebar-left {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}

.content-right {
 display:table-cell;
 float:none;
}
```

I have removed min-height from content-right, as table will not work with it. Also changed float to none. becuase you no longer need it.

Working Demo: http://bootply.com/100790

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the right container height and assign it it to left side navigation bar as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = $(".container").outerHeight(true); 
  s+= "px";
  //alert("height" + s);
  $("#sidebar-left").css("height", s);
  $("#sidebar-left").css("background-color", "grey");


});
```

Comment: thanks for a try, but is their any other way without using Jquery instead of calculating hieght used bootstrap build-in classes

Comment: I think you can do it through CSS only when heights of the left side content and right side content are fixed and static.Otherwise should go with Jquery only..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try warping the whole content area in *.container* .
Saw this in old docs under [Fluid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)

Comment: have tag bootstrap 3,  the link you provided is version 2.3